# Advanced Home Network

Tags: router, home-networking, nas, pxe

As our home network seems to be increasing drastically I was thinking of setting up a network as follows:

- A DMZ between our wireless modem router and the next router (for guests who wish to use our wifi).
- A secondary router where trusted nodes connect via ethernet( TV's, PC's etc).
- A third router with a PXE/DHCP/TFTP server for the nodes to boot from and a NAS server for shared files e.g movies and music.

> ```
>          <-------(DMZ) -------------> (Nodes)
>                    |                     | 
> Internet <--FW-->Modem(Wifi)<--FW--->Router(eth)<---FW-->Router(eth)<--FW-->Servers
> ```

My goal is to have a scalable, secure and monitored network which I can diagnose quickly and manage with very little effort.

My questions is will I achieve my goal by establishing a similar network?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is... Maybe. In the old days, you almost certainly had to set up such a configuration yourself. Modern, off-the-shelf Wi-Fi modems can do all of this in one unit. Independent guest zone with AP isolation, for example, practically fits all your requirements, and you can buy it for less than $200. My Linksys offers this, and ran me about $120, if memory serves. Of course, if you're using older hardware, or just want a challenge, as I often do, I'd say go for it, have fun. Your NAS can be on the private AP node, shaped across trusted devices, with guests unable to see it, but use the Internet. Only one modern router is necessary, and will probably reduce contention over using multiple devices.